# How to add system and hidden attributes to a folder using CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I add system and hidden attributes to all files and folders with this code in cmd:

```
x:\> attrib /d /s +s +h *.*
```

And now I want to add to a specific Folder using attrib command in cmd. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the folder in the command, rather than using wildcards in the root directory:

```
x:\> attrib /d +s +h C:\myfolder\hidefolder
```

Comment: if i want to add these attributes only to this folder and not to files belong of this folder, what code i must to write?

Comment: @Ehsan: just remove the `/s` switch from `attrib` command: `attrib /d +s +h C:\myfolder\hidefolder`

Comment: Thanks my dear friend in other side of world :D

Comment: The `/D` switch is only valid with the `/S` switch.